# Cuando intento llenar mi table con un json de respuesta, no hace nada y se queda vacia

Tags: php, ajax, json

Actualmente tengo un retorno de json que quiero meter en mi datatable pero no hace nada y en lo que a mi respecta es un valor valido:

Retorno del json:

```
Object { NombreProducto: "Refresco", PrecioUnitario: "15", Cantidad: "5", Importe: 75, Acciones: "<div class='col-lg-12'><div class='row'><div class='col-lg-6'>EL</div><div class='col-lg-6'>Up</div></div></div>" }
```

Lo construto de la siguiente forma:

```
echo json_encode(array( 'NombreProducto' => $row["NombreProducto"], 'PrecioUnitario' => $row["PrecioUnitario"], 'Cantidad' => $_POST["Cantidad"],'Importe' => $importe ,'Acciones' => $Acciones ));
```

Mi tabla esta asi:

```
<table id="tb_AddProducto" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Importe</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Importe</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

El llenado de mi ajax esta asi:

```
$.ajax({  
                url: "back_end/GetAddProduct.php",
                type: "post",  
                 dataType: 'json',
                data: {selectProduct:""+$Product+"",Cantidad:""+$Cantidad+""},
                error:function(xhr, status, error){
                  alert("error");
                },
                success: function(data) {

                table.rows.add(data).draw();
                console.log(data);


                }
            });
```

Pero simplemente no se llena.

**Update**

Así inicio el datatable en el document.ready:

```
   table= $('#tb_AddProducto').DataTable( {
 "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros por Pagina",
            "zeroRecords": "No se Encontro Nada - Lo Sentimos",
            "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
            "sSearch": "Buscar",
            "oPaginate": {
    "sFirst":    "Primero",
    "sLast":     "Último",
    "sNext":     "Siguiente",
    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
  }
        }
      });
```

Comment: El `datatable` como lo inicializas? O con ese ajax es que debería inicializarse y llenarse?

Comment: @CesarRomero ya actualice le post indicando como inicio el datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de tu archivo `php` debe cumplir un formato mínimo; debe incluir

- **`draw`** : El contador de `draw` al que responde este objeto - a partir del parámetro de `draw` enviado como parte de la solicitud de datos. (debe ser un numero entero).
- **`recordsTotal`** : Total de registros, antes del filtrado (es decir, el número total de registros en la base de datos)
- **`recordsFiltered`** : Registros totales, después del filtrado (es decir, el número total de registros después de la aplicación del filtrado, no solo el número de registros que se devuelven para esta página de datos).
- **`data`** : Los datos a mostrar en la tabla. Esta es una matriz de objetos de origen de datos, uno para cada fila, que serán utilizados por DataTables.

Deben estar en orden a como se mostraran en la tabla (Cantidad, Precio Unitario, Producto, Importe, Acciones)

[mas información](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data)

```
echo json_encode(array("draw" => 1, "recordsTotal" => 1, "recordsFiltered" => 1,
"data" => array(
    array($_POST["Cantidad"], $row["PrecioUnitario"], $row["NombreProducto"],$importe, $Acciones)
)));
```

Obteniendo algo como esto

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 1,
    "recordsFiltered": 1,
    "data": [
        [
            "5",
            "15",
            "Refresco",
            75,
            "<div class='col-lg-12'><div class='row'><div class='col-lg-6'>EL</div><div class='col-lg-6'>Up</div></div></div>" 
        ]
    ]
}
```